# How are shock waves related to sound, and are there equations describing its density, size, and pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

How exactly does one model a shock wave? I've done a lot of searching and have failed to find any equations where we're able to relate things such as its pressure, density, temperature etc.

I've recently read some dubious claims regarding the 1883 eruption of Krakatoa which prompted me to do a bit of research of my own into shock waves and how they're related to sound intensity. If you do a bit of reading about Krakatoa, you'll find that the eruptions were heard up to 4,000km away, there's even a claim of a shock wave with a pressure of 8.5 kPa 65 km away from the volcano. I've failed to come up with a good way of relating this to the initial pressure of the shock wave at the source, I only end up with wacky answers.The question has also come up about at which point a shock wave ceases to be a shock wave.

I then tried looking into the physics of a shock wave, but the problem I've encountered is that pressures and temperatures are so ridiculously high that any useful approximations break down.

**The no-fluff question**: How are shock waves modeled mathematically in terms of density, pressure, temperature and volume.

Comment: What relations did you find that breakdown? Because the relations for an ideal gas hold pretty well up to hypersonic Mach numbers (roughly ~5).

Comment: I was looking at the shock wave produced by the Tsar Bomba, and it turns out it produced a pressure of 2,000 kPa or so. I always thought the ideal has law only held for pressures around 100 kPa?

Comment: I simulate detonation waves at 40 GPa, so something like 2000 kPa isn't really all that much, and the ideal gas law still holds (provided the values for $c_p$ and $c_v$ are okay). 100 kPa is less than 1 atmosphere, so I don't know where you got the idea the ideal gas law doesn't hold for more than 1 atm but that's definitely incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-dimensional shocks are modeled using the Rankine-Hugoniot relations. These give the jump in density, pressure, and temperature across an infinitely thin shock and are found by conducting a control-volume analysis of the region around the shock (conservation of mass, energy and momentum).

The relations are:

$$\frac{p_2}{p_1} = 1 + \frac{2 \gamma}{\gamma + 1}(M_1^2 -1)$$

$$\frac{\rho_2}{\rho_1} = \frac{u_1}{u_2} = \frac{(\gamma + 1)M_1^2}{2+(\gamma-1)M_1^2}$$

and a similar expression can be found to relate Mach numbers and temperatures. $\gamma$ is the ratio of specific heats, which is constant for calorically perfect gases and a function of temperature for thermally perfect gases.

These expressions hold provided your $\gamma$ is good. It's important to note that as all of the energy modes get excited, $\gamma \rightarrow 1$ which is a commonly used approximation in hypersonic flows, ie. flows where $M_1 ~ 5$.

For hypersonic flow under the assumption $M_1 \rightarrow \infty$:

$$ \frac{p_2}{p_1} = \frac{2\gamma}{\gamma+1}M_1^2\sin^2\beta$$

$$ \frac{\rho_2}{\rho_1} = \frac{\gamma+1}{\gamma-1} $$

$$ \frac{T_2}{T_1} = \frac{2\gamma(\gamma-1)}{(\gamma+1)^2}M_1^2\sin^2\beta$$

where $\beta$ is the angle of the shock, so $\beta=\pi/2$ is for a normal shock.

These expressions are used essentially until chemical reactions start to kick in when the air ionizes or there are other significant non-equilibrium effects.

In this analysis, the shock wave is infinitely thin giving a discontinuous jump from the pressure ahead, to the pressure behind. In real life, shocks have a finite thickness but it is on the order of ~10 mean-free-paths, which for air is on the order of microns. So ridiculously thin. The finite thickness is due to viscosity within the shock-wave itself, which is absent in the Euler equations used to find these relations.

In the case of a bomb blowing up, things are more complicated than what you have here. The initial [blast wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blast_wave) propagates out, but this will eventually leave a region behind the blast that is at a very low pressure, and so an expansion wave travels back towards the origin of the blast. When the expansion wave gets to the origin, they all end up colliding and creating a region of high pressure again which sends out another shock. And so on and so on until the pressure is back to atmospheric. So when you see a peak pressure reported for a bomb/detonation/etc, it is actually the value at a peak because the wave itself will look like ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blast_wave)):

[image]

where that undershoot from the expansion wave is pretty clear.

Finally, there is a distinction between a blast wave and a detonation wave. A detonation wave is one in which the shock front and the reaction front are coupled together (so the reaction front is moving at supersonic speeds) and continuously reinforces the shock front. A blast wave is not coupled to a reaction front. So when you see the videos of bombs exploding, it starts as a detonation in the solid phase (which is generally too small and fast to see) and then you'll see the blast wave expanding outwards with a giant fireball behind it (if it is an explosive that generates a fireball that is). The fireball doesn't move outwards at the same speed as the blast wave, so it is no longer a detonation at that point.

Comment: Ah OK, this is sort of what I'm looking for. I think I may not have fully understood what is meant by the pressure of a shock wave, so let me ask another question. When we say that the pressure of the shock wave was 2000 kPa, what region is that referring to? I was under the impression it was describing the shock wave itself, but is it actually in reference to the region that's "chasing" the shock wave? I'm still confused about the properties of the wave front, its thickness and density primarily.

Comment: @Astrum You had asked about shock waves, which can be analyzed pretty basically. But bombs and detonations are more complicated to analyze. I added some info to my answer to address your comment.